# Set width of td to auto?

Tags: css

I have a a `td` with an inline style setting its `width` as a percentage. I can modify the css but not the html.

How can I make the `td` only take up the width required by its contents?

The following CSS doesn't work:

```
td#my 
{
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Perhaps check out http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout for a detailed explanation of how table widths are calculated and different ways to set this kinda stuff up.

Comment: Can you give us some more context?  The table `html` structure at the very least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells are auto width by default, they however take up the minimum width of the widest cell in their column. So take this for example

```
td1|td2|td3|

1  |2  |3  |
```

Those cells will all be the same width based on the first row. There is no way I can think of to force it to do this:

```
td1|td2|td3|

1|2|3|
```

Which is what it sounds like you're trying to do, not without changing the HTML anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to respect CSS Specificity rules. (doing so can avoid the use of !important)

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

inline styles weigh in at 1000 where ID's are 100 and elements are 1. So to ensure proper use of your css rules you will need to pay close attention to this. The article linked above does a much better job at explaining specificity than I could ever hope to achieve. Read it, study it, love it.

Where this doesn't directly answer your question: it is a informative article and may in fact solve your problem by allowing you to take a different route.

Comment: Unless the inline styles also have `!important` this is not the issue OP is having.

Comment: @ZachL I mention this does not solve his direct issue, however it is worth reading and if applied correctly he can avoid the use of `!important` and still have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to make some changes to the css for other cells of the table as well.  Dig into the following to see how cell width is calculated

From:  [w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout](http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#width-layout)

> Column widths are determined as follows:
>
> 1. Calculate the minimum content width (MCW) of each cell: the formatted
>      content may span any number of lines but may not overflow the cell
>      box. If the specified 'width' (W) of the cell is greater than MCW, W
>      is the minimum cell width. A value of 'auto' means that MCW is the
>      minimum cell width.
>      Blockquote
>
>    Also, calculate the "maximum" cell width of each cell: formatting the
>      content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks
>      occur.
> 2. For each column, determine a maximum and minimum column width from the
>      cells that span only that column. The minimum is that required by the
>      cell with the largest minimum cell width (or the column 'width',
>      whichever is larger). The maximum is that required by the cell with
>      the largest maximum cell width (or the column 'width', whichever is
>      larger).
> 3. For each cell that spans more than one column, increase the minimum
>      widths of the columns it spans so that together, they are at least as
>      wide as the cell. Do the same for the maximum widths. If possible,
>      widen all spanned columns by approximately the same amount.
> 4. For each column group element with a 'width' other than 'auto',
>      increase the minimum widths of the columns it spans, so that together
>      they are at least as wide as the column group's 'width'.
>
> This gives a maximum and minimum width for each column.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`td#my {width:inherit !important;}`

or

`td#my {width:0% !important;}`

Comment: there's a difference between `td #my` and `td#my`